# Is the GMC (ganglion mother cell) in Drosphila the same thing as the basal daughter cell? Does a highly active Notch pathway obstruct cell division?

Tags: neuroscience

"Numb acts as a negative regulator of the Notch pathway (discussed above), which keeps Notch pathway activity low in the GMC. Low Notch activity causes the de-repression of proneural genes, as well as the arrest of proliferation (after one more mitoses) of the GMC. By contrast, in the basal daughter cell, Notch pathway activity is kept high by proteins of the apical com- plex (Par-3, Insc), which promotes continued division of this cell" (*Fundamental Neuroscience* by Larry Squire on page 316). This statement confused me for two reasons. First of all, they originally stated that the basal daughter cell was the GMC (ganglion mother cell), so the two statements would be contradicting because the Notch pathway cannot be low and high at the same time. In addition, (please correct me if I'm mistaken), doesn't a highly active Notch pathway obstruct cell division?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please, consider including a reference in your question